# List in List C# ASP.Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, model

Подскажите как правельно вложить List в модель с присвоением значений из модели - для формирования JsonResult в MasterDetail

Значение "Test2"принимается нормально, а вот с присвоением проблема
Инициализатор поля не может обращаться к нестатическому полю, методу или свойству "List1".

```
public class List1 {

public int Id { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string SecondName { get; set; }

public string Login { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
    public List<Test> Test { get; set; } = new List<Test>
    {
        new Test() { Name = Login, Age = "Age1" },  
        new Test() { Name = "Test2", Age = "Age2" }            
    };
}

public  class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Вы пытаетесь использовать свойство `Name` в инициализаторе другого свойства `Test` - такое не прокатит. Да и какое значение вы туда подставить хотите? А что, если `Name` будет инициализировано после `Test`? А если до `Test`? Если вам такое надо, то пишите код инициализации в конструкторе класса.

Comment: Так, подождите, а что именно вы хотите получить? У вас при инициализации `Login` еще не инициализирован, а вы уже хотите его куда-то впихнуть. Я вообще в этом смысла не вижу.

Comment: Данные берутся из БД, при инициализации конечно данных нет но при формировании запроса данные должны потянуться